Unable to login Supabase user on Safari?
I'm trying to add Playwright tests to my Nuxt3/Supabase application, however tests are failing in Webkit/Safari due to some https issues. Logging in on Chrome works fine. Here are the errors I'm seeing:

I have a couple of scripts in my package.json to enable https (again, works fine in Chrome):
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 nuxt dev --https --ssl-cert localhost.pem --ssl-key localhost-key.pem",
    "cert": "mkcert -key-file ./localhost-key.pem -cert-file ./localhost.pem localhost"
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxt/devtools": "latest",
    "@nuxt/test-utils": "^3.12.1",
    "@nuxtjs/supabase": "^1.1.6",
    "@playwright/test": "^1.43.1",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.4.5",
    "nuxt": "^3.8.2",
    "supabase": "^1.145.4",
    "supawright": "^0.2.0",
    "tsx": "^4.7.3",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3",
    "vue": "^3.3.10",
    "vue-router": "^4.2.5",
    "vue-tsc": "^1.8.26"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  }

I've also tried opening my Safari preferences and disabling cross-origin restrictions. It doesn't appear that Supabase has a way to serve auth over https in a local Docker environment.
At this point, I'm just really not sure where to go? I might be forced to skip testing on Safari which I'd prefer not to do, however if I'm unable to find a solution I may not have a choice.
Edit:
Discovered that I can set the location of the .pem files directly in my Nuxt config like so:
  devServer: {
    port: 8000,
    https: {
      key: fs.readFileSync('./localhost-key.pem')
        .toString(),
      cert: fs.readFileSync('./localhost.pem')
        .toString(),
    },
  },

after which I reverted my script to simply use nuxt dev. This doesn't solve the issue unfortunately, though it does simplify the process in getting https working in Nuxt. Also discovered perusing the NuxtSupabase GitHub issues that this isn't uncommon or unknown either, even though this ticket has been closed. The provided solution didn't solve it for me unfortunately.

Strange that the flag did not solve the issue, maybe it's unrelated and the issue is something else? (even tho the error looks quite explicit) The issue is only while you're working in dev right? Is it an issue for tests in a CI/CD? You could work on Chrome and run your tests on a staging environment if Safari is picky in a dev environment. Do you also have the issue in Firefox, just to double-check if the error might be different? Otherwise, I think that you should reach out to the communities on GH/Discord or other places to double-check a possible workaround.

@kissu It's still in development so I don't have any of this working in CI/CD quite yet. I just replaced Safari with Firefox in my playwright config though, and those tests passed so it's something very specific to Safari it seems like.

Hm, then I guess you're in a treat to spend some hours on forums searching why Safari is annoying... Maybe give a try to a Canari/Nightly edition, might be less strict maybe? I would still try on the Supabase side because it might totally be possible and you have more leverage on that part than on Safari's. Otherwise, you could try to setup a quick CI/CD workflow and live your life on staging for testing purposes even if it's not optimal. Depends if you're a daily Safari user or just doing it for a double-check testing purpose only. The second looks fine as a workaround. Good luck with mate!

Hey I appreciate it! I updated my original post with some findings that I thought were interesting.

Hm double-weird. Maybe link them to this issue as a following comment? Great discovery!
